# AngularJS: module inclusion among separated controllers

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Assuming we have two AngularJS controllers in separate files that are included in an HTML file, like this:

```
//controller1.js
"use strict";
var someApp = angular.module('MYAPP');
//var someApp = angular.module('MYAPP',['ngCookies']); <-- Does not work

someApp.controller('Controller1', function($scope) {

    $scope.CookieFunction = function(){
        //foo
    };
});   


//controller2.js
"use strict";
var someApp = angular.module('MYAPP',['ngCookies','ui.bootstrap']);

someApp.controller('Controller2', function($scope,$cookies) {

    $scope.SomeOtherfunction = function(){
        //foo
    };
}); 

//HTML file
<script src="controller1.js"></script>
<script src="controller2.js"></script>
```

Inside controller1, I'd like to perform some Cookie operation, hence need to include ngCookies. If I do so inside controller1.js, then controller2 gets undefined. I prefer to include modules exactly where I need them and not somewhere else. How can I achieve that without "erasing" subsequent controllers?

EDIT: If I move ngCookies inclusion from controller2 to controller1, I get this error message (Argument 'controller2' is not a function, got undefined)

Comment: You can't 'erase subsequent controllers' unless they have the same name....what do you mean? What does _"If I do so inside controller1.js, then controller2 gets undefined."_ mean? You'll have to clarify, because your question is extremely vague as is.

Comment: I updated the code above. It means that if I move the ngCookies inclusion from controller2 to controller1 (where I actually use it), then controller2 will become undefined!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by making different modules as below. Also this is the preffered way when we want to modularize our application.

```
 //app.js
"use strict";
var mainApp = angular.module('MYAPP', ['SomeApp', 'OtherApp']);


 //controller1.js
var someApp = angular.module('SomeApp',['ngCookies']);
someApp.controller('Controller1', function($scope,$cookies) {

    $scope.CookieFunction = function(){
        //foo
    };
});   


//controller2.js
"use strict";
var otherApp = angular.module('OtherApp ',[]);

otherApp.controller('Controller2', function($scope) {

    $scope.SomeOtherfunction = function(){
        //foo
    };
}); 

//HTML file
<script src="app.js"></script>
<script src="controller1.js"></script>
<script src="controller2.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you give a second argument to angular.module, such as `angular.module('MYAPP',['ngCookies'])`, you are defining a *new* module and it's associated dependencies. If you don't include the second argument (the dependencies), then the function acts as a 'getter', and simply returns a reference to that module, with which you can register more controllers/services/etc. If you specify `angular.module('MYAPP', ['ngCookies'])` more than once, you are overwriting your previous 'MYAPP' module, which is why Controller1 seems to get "erased"

Since you included ngCookies via `angular.module('MYAPP',['ngCookies']) already in the file that Controller2 is in, you don't need to do it again in the file that Controller1 is in. You should be able use $cookies just fine Controller1 - just make sure you inject it. i.e.

```
someApp.controller('Controller1', function($scope, $cookies) {

    $scope.CookieFunction = function(){
        //foo
    };
});
```

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that. I did not mean to include ngCookies in both files, JUST IN controller1.js. But why can't I do that, without controller2.js getting undefined then?

Comment: Because angular.module('moduleName') is a essentially a 'getter', while angular.module('moduleName' ['dependency1', 'dependency2', 'etc']) is a 'setter' . When you 'set' it more than once, you basically overwrite the first instance. When you specify a second argument, it basically declares a new module and its dependencies. You only need to do that once. You can use the getter syntax (1 argument only) as much as you want to register more controllers/directives/services/etc on the module as much as you want.

Comment: But that means, I can only include modules in ONE file and not where I actually need it. So if I had 20 separate files, I always had to remember where I included the neccessary modules and look up that file to check if all required modules are included. Why (and how if I can) can't I just just include the respective modules in any file?

Comment: You can only specify the module's dependencies in one place - that is correct. But you can register new controllers/directives/services/etc on that module from anywhere. Personally, I think declaring all your dependencies in one place makes things easier to keep track of than having them spread out and accidentally introducing duplicates into your application. Angular needs to know what all the dependencies are ahead of time so that the dependency injection can work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like that ?

```
//app.js
"use strict";
angular.module('MYAPP', ['myCtrl1', 'myCtrl2']);

//controller1.js
angular.module('myCtrl1', ['ngCookies'])
  .controller('Controller1', function($scope) {

    $scope.CookieFunction = function(){
        //foo
    };
});   


//controller2.js
"use strict";

angular.module('myCtrl2',['ngCookies','ui.bootstrap']);
  .controller('Controller2', function($scope,$cookies) {

    $scope.SomeOtherfunction = function(){
        //foo
    };
});

//HTML file
<script src="app.js"></script>
<script src="controller1.js"></script>
<script src="controller2.js"></script>`
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem in the code example is following (change `[ngCookies]` to `['ngCookies']`)

```
//controller1.js
"use strict";
var someApp = angular.module('MYAPP',['ngCookies']);
```

**Other approach, simplifying to 1 app.js**

```
// app.js
"use strict";
var someApp = angular.module('MYAPP',['ngCookies']); 

someApp.controller('Controller1', function($scope) {

    $scope.CookieFunction = function(){
        //foo
    };
});   

someApp.controller('Controller2', function($scope,$cookies) {

    $scope.SomeOtherfunction = function(){
        //foo
    };
}); 

//HTML file
<script src="app.js"></script>
```

**Simplify to 1 main app.js with different controller files**

If you want to keep controllers in separate file then,

app.js

```
var app = angular.module("testApp",['ngCookies','ui.bootstrap']);
```

test1.js

```
app.controller("controller1",function(){
// some code
})
```

test2.js

```
app.controller("controller2",function(){
// some code
})
```

Finally include js files in html

```
<script src="app.js"></script>
<script src="controller1.js"></script>
<script src="controller2.js"></script>
```

Comment: Updated answer, why not simplify to 1 app.js file?

Comment: Because that's not the only code involved ;) I don't want all code in one file. Let's just assume,  I have many separate files and won't change that. So am I right saying that I can only include modules in ONE file (and not wherever I need it) and, thus, always have to jump back to that file to see if I included all neccessary modules!?

Comment: I usually work as the updated answer, with 1 main app.js file - including sub files if necessary. Just a share of how I bring structure.

Comment: And I appreciate your answer, thank you. I am just trying to find out if there is something wrong with my code or if I am just "tackling some structural limitations" of Angular which I just have to accept and deal with =)

Comment: Seems like that is my only choice. Thanks daan.desmedt.